# dealing with bullying

Tags: bullying, australia, unions

ways to deal with bullying supervisor

I have a sponsorship of an employer for Australia, I am from overseas.
I started working in this Tech company for 1 year on a student visa, after this a sponsorship was granted, for 2 year I have been working on a sponsorship status, for a total of 3 years experience in the company.

Short after the sponsorship status started, my supervisor slowly but constantly has gradually escalated on aggression and psychologyical abuse.

As he knows I need the job, he abuses his position. I have tried to report to our direct boss, but he is on the side of the abusive supervisor.

Im on a stage where Im ready to go back home and leave all the years spent on this experience behind.

I have tried to resolve the differences with my supervisor, and the company owner but after every meeting I just get reminded on how lucky I am to be working for them and suggest I think on my immigration future. Then the supervisor feels encouraged to keep going on at the bullying.

He yells at me in front of other employees, and have been asked even by the wife of the owner of the company to repect. But this gets ignored.

I want to find a strategy to solve this.

among the things i have to endure every day are :contradictory orders,
assign non sensical tasks due to his lack of knowledge,
aggressive behaviour, have my work belittled, is extremely harsh with any of my mistakes, but his mistakes are ignored by him and uper management.

The expected outcome is the residence but im ready to fight this in a court as a case of bullying as now this is affecting my health giving me my first case of panic atack ever.

I have no fear of loosing the time worked, just want some advice on how to proceed as professionaly as possible.

If situation of respect can be stablished I am able to keep working. But im not able to get a heart attack resulting from a daily boiler room.

Shall I contact my workers union, for a legal action?,

shall I mention this contact to the union to my boss?

Comment: Sorry, off topic - "Questions asking for advice on what to do are not practical answerable questions. Questions should get answers explaining why and how to make a decision, not advice on what to do" - voting to close

Comment: Does your worker's union offer advice and support as well as just the jump straight to legal action?

Comment: Second the off-topic. Since OP doesn't seem overly concerned with the threats made regarding his immigration status I also don't see how this differs much from other questions on dealing with bullying. This might be a duplicate for instance: [How can I deal with an abusive manager who publicly belittles me?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13632/how-can-i-deal-with-an-abusive-manager-who-publicly-belittles-me?rq=1)

Comment: FWIW, that's my job too. And I'm not even on sponsorship. The reality is that there are a lot of bad places to work. You, unfortunately, aren't in the position where you simply can go apply for work elsewhere. Unfortunately, that's usually the only viable solution. I wish you the best. Good luck with it all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Shall I contact my workers union

Yes.

This is what workers unions are for.

> shall I mention this contact to the union to my boss

Based on your description, I'd say there's no need to discuss *anything* with your boss unless you absolutely need to. This is not one of them.

Unfortunately, what you describe isn't uncommon. There are a lot of incompetent people in management that either intentionally or unintentionally end up acting like bullies to their reports. The typical solution is to just quit and go find another gig. That doesn't sound like an option in your case, which is unfortunate. However, the union might very well be a possible solution in this situation.