# My superiors (directors of company) are actually targeting me twice into a dilemma that I will need to resign

Tags: resignation, task-management, personal-problems, malaysia

I am actually in a very bad situation, I will try to explain as clearly as possible.

I started my internship at this startup company and then following up as a permanent staff last year. I am actually  working as a programmer but towards to front end of web design only.

The startup company where am I working has no proper system like having how many annual leave, sick leave or even salary pay slips.

Throughout the whole year as in 2016 until today, I realised I learn only into web responsive. For everyone, its like a simple task, but for me some of the requirements in the web layout they want don't seems to be logical. I try asking my colleague but they can't understand what I mean because I really don't talk normally like other people do.

Each day, my projects were about that until 4 months ago I was suddenly ignored and not even called to meetings or any company trips to discuss proposals and no training.

So one day my first director was in a bad mood and I got a good scolding for not being able to complete it on time. He knew that I was slacking on my job where I kept on my phone and scroll videos and yes I did that simply because I couldn't find anymore references to read and I just don't know what to do or react or even to whom to turn.

Then, my second director came to me and spoke in front of everyone. I felt ashamed because they joke around about me until they crossed the line.

To me it was enough. Yes, if I said that, you could judge, there's no privacy or such stuff except certain project clients only. The root of my problem was myself, I simply couldn't find anymore motivation or rather an imburse to continue my job because I couldn't solve anything, I couldn't focus on things easily.

Is this the time where I should leave the company? I did research on this forum, lots of similar situations but not as mine.

ADDITIONAL NOTE : My close friend who is now working with me has a better position  in the company than me simply because he has better performance than me .It not something of a jealousy but rather their treatment towards him was a bit better than mine.For instance ,a casual talk,they(directors) always refer him or joke with him but treatment  to me its like a transparent glass.

How it happen is when the directors hired a new colleague few months ago who somehow show her skills better than me and asked me to mentor her, my reaction was like (is this a joke or something) i ask  for assistance because my friend do not want to do front-end job because hes more capable at the backend programming. I still got a lot to learn but this new colleague somehow turn to my directors instead and change to another job scope which is designing,i dont know whats going on but things doesnt seem right for now.i know maybe its my slacking problem too or what.

In terms of co-workers ,they didn't do really treat me bad ,all of them was like family ,we simply roast each other with harsh joke that we could  take it,i refer they (directors) instead.

UPDATE: thanks for the advices and also certain situation quite helping me .It comes to the end that we had an argument between me and my 1st director.Obviously it was me who is in the fault ,nonetheless i have decide to look for a new job and resign after finding it .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I deal with an abusive manager who publicly belittles me?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13632/how-can-i-deal-with-an-abusive-manager-who-publicly-belittles-me)

Comment: @HerbWolfe i seen his case before i start posted ,unfortunately this company has no managers or supervisor ,this company is lead by two directors on hands

Comment: What's your language issue? Do you have a speech impediment? Or do you simply not speak the same native language that your colleagues do? Follow your gut, but don't do anything too rash either. It's a lot easier to find another job, when you're already employed and have a bit of money in front of you.

Comment: they speak  towards to thier mother tongue more while i am more converse to english.I am actually now employed but this company ,i cant feel the company's future

Comment: "The startup company where am I working has no proper system like having how many annual leave, sick leave or even salary pay slips." Did you sign a contract at least? In which country is this? How do they pay you?
 With cash or check? You should keep a back up at home of your email messages and your repository contribution timeline. With that, you should be able to prove which days you were working at least. Just don't copy any code or do anything too illegal, or that might get you in trouble if they find out.

Comment: Can you look for a new employer that has more colleagues speaking your language(s)? Do you think that's the only reason they make fun of you, because of the language issue?

Comment: @k.kit [The link post](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13632/how-can-i-deal-with-an-abusive-manager-who-publicly-belittles-me) applies to abuse from any supervisor (which includes directors). There aren't any options apart from what's stated there (and just living with it, I suppose). Do be sure to note the disclaimers in the answers.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk they prefer i get a new colleague  form a circle of friends ,problem is they all hired .I am actually living in malaysia .I got a contractand already signed ,they just bank in the salary thats all.

Comment: @Dukeling hes lucky because hes has people backing up him but i am only a one man army and whenever the directors sound it ,nobody speaking up for me ,i try never to say no because i really want to show  my work but not in manner where you ask me to build a well but instead expecting to have water underground of well

Comment: I'll repeat what gnasher answered already. You must leave, but not before finding yourself a new job at a different company with colleagues that actually speak one of your languages.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk i understood ,but i would strongly pin point language isn't the main problem

Comment: @k.kit, Well, I didn't think it was completely a language problem. Language is also a marker. Language could be linked to a group identity. And you might be an easy target because you don't have the same identity as your colleagues. In any case, it's just an idea. I don't know if it's true. Only you would know if something like that is happening.

Comment: They are not putting a new colleague for you to be the mentor, but to shadow you - between you being ignored and shadowed, all the writing is in the wall. Ignore all the provocations, they just want to have an excuse to fire you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It’s not time to leave the company.

There is one thing you absolutely need to do before you think about leaving: You need to find a new job first and sign a contract, and then you give notice.

And since you have no wage slips, I’d ask the tax office whether all your income tax has been paid. If not, your bosses are in trouble, and deservedly so (up to jail time).

Comment: they paid something like social fund for workers called EPF in malaysia .my salary is not even 3k so theres no income tax but rather a slip that i registered with income tax

Answer (score 2):

> Is this the time where I should leave the company?

I must say I really sympathise with your situation. Take a deep breath, relax, and think it through.

If you should quit is really your call. If you no longer like that job you may consider leaving for one better fit to you (possibly some place with good mentoring so this doesn't happen again).

Before that, you can also try to approach your manager and explain to him what you feel, and that you would like more mentoring on the technology (or any other alternative) so you can improve your performance.

If you have difficulties communicating verbally, you can try **writing down your thoughs on paper** before meeting your boss, or even try to *structure it like a speech* so you can read it and communicate what you want effectively.

Now, the jokes from your coworkers is another story, so I suggest you do one thing at a time and solve this after talking to you director about the other issue.

Just make sure you think it through and consider your options, so you can decide if it is worth trying to get the mentoring and improving or you would prefer leaving. If you decide to leave make sure you star job hunting ASAP. Good luck.

Comment: Just an observation but writing may not be the way to go either...

Comment: @Y12K How so? It's an effective thing to do especially when saying complicated or sensible things (plus OP said he had trouble *speaking* and phrasing his problems) I was suggesting options for the OP to try, even though it were true what you say, it is also possible that it actually helps in some way. If you have other POV on this consider leaving an answer :)

Comment: theres no manager or supervisor on this company .I forgot to explain further .My second directors handles this problem.This person has confront me thrice to be honest ,the more that person explain ,it gets worse because honestly its not helping at all

Comment: @k.kit by manager I mean the one you report to, call it boss, manager director etc.

Comment: the person is in charge of those is also my directors ,i mention this isnt some big cooperation but rather small startup company